# How to align numbers in a table with different character width?

Tags: tables

I try to align some HEX numbers in the style of 0x1FFFF and 0x00001 in a table.
They have to be aligned to the right, but I also want them to have the same witdh per character, despite an F beeing a lot wider than a 0 or any other number.
Otherwise it looks really silly when the 0x in the beginning do not aling with each other...

This code here

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}} 
\toprule
\textbf{DEC} \hspace{10mm}      & \textbf{HEX} \\ 
\midrule
1           & 0x00001  \\
2           & 0x00002  \\
100         & 0x00064  \\   
131.071     & 0x1FFFF  \\
262143      & 0x3FFFF  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

creates this table

[image]

Is there some way to align the numbers on the right properly, so that I does not look like different amount of digits?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You probably need a monospaced font...

Comment: GOV.UK has a separate font which is identical to their main font, but with equally spaced characters. The font is specifically for tabular data like this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Same width per character means that you need a font which matches this requirement. Usually that's a mono-spaced font you can access with `\texttt`.

[image: hex]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}l>{\ttfamily}r@{}} 
\toprule
\textbf{DEC} \hspace{10mm}      & \textbf{HEX} \\ 
\midrule
1           & 0x00001  \\
2           & 0x00002  \\
100         & 0x00064  \\   
131.071     & 0x1FFFF  \\
262143      & 0x3FFFF  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, that seems a bit curious, when one column is in a different style, but it works. Thanks ;)

Comment: is the `\arraybackslash` in the socund column definition really needed? also instead of `\begin{center} ... `\end{center}` is better `\centering`  and all columns to use the same font family :)

Comment: @Zarko Well, no. And you're right. I'll update.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of a real monospaced font you could also fake it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand*{\fakemonochar}[1]{\makebox[.6em][c]{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\fakemonotext}[1]{%
  \@fakemonotext#1\\%
}
\newcommand*{\@fakemonotext}[1]{%
  \ifx #1\\\else\fakemonochar{#1}\expandafter\@fakemonotext\fi
}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lrr@{}} 
\toprule
\textbf{DEC} & \textbf{HEX} (faked) & \textbf{HEX} (mono)\\ 
\midrule
1           & \fakemonotext{0x00001} & \texttt{0x00001} \\
2           & \fakemonotext{0x00002} & \texttt{0x00002} \\
100         & \fakemonotext{0x00064} & \texttt{0x00064} \\   
131.071     & \fakemonotext{0x1FFFF} & \texttt{0x1FFFF} \\
262143      & \fakemonotext{0x3FFFF} & \texttt{0x3FFFF} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: comparing faked monospaced and real monospaced]

Comment: Very nice idea.

Comment: @TeXnician I do not like the faked monospace. The letters are OK, but the digits … ugly. If I could, I would down-vote this answer. ;-)

Comment: I do not like the appearance either, but I like the idea to fake mono with boxes.

Comment: @TeXnician You could also use `\newcommand*{\fakemonotext}[1]{\makebox[4em][s]{\fontdimen4\font=\fontdimen2\font #1}}` and `\fakemonotext{0x0 0 0 0 1}`. This could even be used with a `p`-column with initial `\fontdimen` change. Then you would not need `\fakemonotext`. But the input in both cases have to be with spaces to have inter word space between the hex digits.

Answer (score 3):

You can let TeX do the computations!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,booktabs,siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hexnum}{ O{ \l_hexnum_pad_int } m }
 {
  \hexnum_print:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\hexrow}{ O{ \l_hexnum_pad_int } m }
 {
  \num{#2} & \hexnum_print:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\sethexnumpad}{m}
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l_hexnum_pad_int { #1 }
 }

\int_new:N \l_hexnum_pad_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hexnum_print:nn
 {
  \texttt{ 0x \hexnum_pad:nf { #1 } { \int_to_Hex:n { #2 } } }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \hexnum_pad:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nF { #1 == 0 }
  {
   \prg_replicate:nn { #1 - \tl_count:n { #2 } } { 0 }
  }
  #2
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hexnum_pad:nn { nf }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\sethexnumpad{5} % initialize

\begin{document}

Stand alone: \hexnum[0]{35671} or \hexnum{35671}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ l r }
\toprule
{DEC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{HEX} \\
\midrule
\hexrow{1} \\
\hexrow{2} \\
\hexrow{100} \\
\hexrow{131071} \\
\hexrow{262143} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%
\sethexnumpad{8}
%
\begin{tabular}{ l r }
\toprule
{DEC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{HEX} \\
\midrule
\hexrow[1]{1} \\
\hexrow{2} \\
\hexrow{100} \\
\hexrow{131071} \\
\hexrow{262143} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The padding is done to `\l_hexnum_pad_int` digits, which you can set either with `\sethexnumpad` or with the optional argument to `\hexnum` (or `\hexrow` that's a wrapper to it). If the value is set to 0, no padding is done.

[image]